# Pandas conditionally select column values based on data from other dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Is there a way that I can create a new column in a dataframe by selecting values from different columns from another dataframe based on some conditions in the first dataframe?

My data sets are like this:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(
    [['USA', 1992],
    ['China', 1993],
    ['Japan', 1994]],
    columns = ['Country', 'year'])
scores = pd.DataFrame(
    [['USA', 20, 30, 40],
    ['China', 5, 15, 30],
    ['Japan', 30, 50, 40],
    ['Korea', 10, 15, 20],
    ['France', 10, 12, 15]],
    columns = ['Country', 1992, 1993, 1994])
```

And my desired dataset would be:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    [['USA', 1992, 20]
    ['China', 1993, 15]
    ['Japan', 1994, 40]],
    columns = ['Country', 'year', 'score'])
```

I have tried using apply with a lambda function but it gives me a

```
KeyError: ('Country', u'occurred at index Country')
```

the line that I have tried is:

```
df1['score'] = df.apply(lambda x: scores[scores['Country'] == x['Country']][x['year']][1])
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What are the conditions? How do you want to select them? We cannot figure that out from your code since your code isn't working.

Comment: @ayhan I think the previous edit was missing the scores dataframe hence causing the confusion. I was trying to add a new score column to the df1 based on the year columns of df1. Thanks

Comment: Ah yes, sorry about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can melt the `scores`  DataFrame and merge it with the original:

```
scores = pd.melt(scores, id_vars='Country', value_name='score', var_name='year')
df1.merge(scores)
Out: 
  Country  year  score
0     USA  1992     20
1   China  1993     15
2   Japan  1994     40
```

`merge` by default merges on common columns. If you want to specify the column names, you can use the `on`  parameter (i.e. `df1.merge(scores, on=['Country', 'year'])`)

Comment: Have not known the melt function before, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Country` as an index on `scores` DataFrame:

```
scores = scores.set_index(['Country'])
```

Then you will be able to apply the function `get_score`, creating and filling the `score` column with the desired value:

```
def get_score(row):
    row['score'] = scores.loc[row['Country'], row['year']]
    return row

df = df1.apply(get_score, axis=1)
```

Which gives you this output:

```
  Country  year  score
0     USA  1992     20
1   China  1993     15
2   Japan  1994     40
```